# AngularJs - How To Call Parent Controller Inside Same JSP

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS,  I am calling parent controller functions in same JSP inside child div [Bootstrap Modal].

If i use same controller name in child div, so i can able to call parent functions but i am unable to use parent scope data. How to call validationUsingParentScope function & to use parent scope date without using child controller.

Bootstrap Modal div is not in parent scope even we put their code in same jsp. We need to give ng-controller="parent" in that modal div to use parent controller functions.

I have written every js functions inside controller "parent".

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="parent as data" id="PARENT_DIV">

    <div ng-controller="parent" class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" id="CHILD_DIV" aria-hidden="true">
        // BOOTSTRAP MODAL CODE
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label> <input
                            id="name"
                            ng-model="data.name" 
                            type="text"
                            ng-blur="validationUsingParentScope(this.data)"/>
                    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: there is any specific reason you want to create a parent and a child controller i cant see the benefit on this example its only make things more complicated. Apart from this i suggest you to check for parent child communication through a service

Comment: Bootstrap Modal div is not in parent scope even we put their code in same jsp. We need to give ng-controller="parent" in that modal div to use parent controller functions